# Why do i get results in the web client even though the server is off?

Tags: c#, web-services, web

I am a web service applications beginner.
I wrote a web service application and a simple web client application in order to test the service.
It works fine, but i found out that even when the service application (that runs another application) is off, i can get the result at the client side.

Is it ok? If not, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two possible explanations -

Either pages are cached somewhere (client, proxy servers, web servers) or the client does find a server (as in - it isn't off, or it doesn't go to the server you think it is)